# Python Spark combineByKey Average

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to learn Spark in Python, and am stuck with `combineByKey` for averaging the values in key-value pairs.  In fact, my confusion is not with the `combineByKey` syntax, but what comes afterward.  The typical example (from the O'Rielly 2015 Learning Spark Book) can be seen on the web in many places; [here's one](https://github.com/mahmoudparsian/pyspark-tutorial/blob/master/tutorial/combine-by-key/spark-combineByKey.md).

The problem is with the `sumCount.map(lambda (key, (totalSum, count)): (key, totalSum / count)).collectAsMap()` statement.  Using spark 2.0.1 and iPython 3.5.2, this throws a syntax error exception.  Simplifying it to something that should work (and is what's in the O'Reilly book): `sumCount.map(lambda key,vals: (key, vals[0]/vals[1])).collectAsMap()` causes Spark to go bats**t crazy with java exceptions, but I do note a `TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'v'` error.

Can anyone point me to an example of this functionality that actually works with a recent version of Spark & Python?  For completeness, I've included my own minimum working (or rather, non-working) example:

```
In: pRDD = sc.parallelize([("s",5),("g",3),("g",10),("c",2),("s",10),("s",3),("g",-1),("c",20),("c",2)])
In: cbk = pRDD.combineByKey(lambda x:(x,1), lambda x,y:(x[0]+y,x[1]+1),lambda x,y:(x[0]+y[0],x[1]+y[1]))
In: cbk.collect()
Out: [('s', (18, 3)), ('g', (12, 3)), ('c', (24, 3))]
In: cbk.map(lambda key,val:(k,val[0]/val[1])).collectAsMap() <-- errors
```

It's easy enough to compute `[(e[0],e[1][0]/e[1][1]) for e in cbk.collect()]`, but I'd rather get the "Sparkic" way working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step by step:

- `lambda (key, (totalSum, count)): ...` is so-called [Tuple Parameter Unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/) which has been removed in Python.
- `RDD.map` takes a function which expect as single argument. Function you try to use:

  ```
  lambda key, vals: ...
  ```

  Is a function which expects two arguments, not a one. A valid translation from 2.x syntax would be

  ```
  lambda key_vals: (key_vals[0], key_vals[1][0] / key_vals[1][1])
  ```

  or:

  ```
  def get_mean(key_vals):
      key, (total, cnt) = key_vals
      return key, total / cnt

  cbk.map(get_mean)
  ```

  You can also make this much simpler with `mapValues`:

  ```
  cbk.mapValues(lambda x: x[0] / x[1])
  ```
- Finally a numerically stable solution would be:

  ```
  from pyspark.statcounter import StatCounter

  (pRDD
      .combineByKey(
          lambda x: StatCounter([x]),
          StatCounter.merge,
          StatCounter.mergeStats)
      .mapValues(StatCounter.mean))
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Averaging over a specific column value can be done by using the *Window* concept. Consider the following code:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window
df = spark.createDataFrame([('a', 2), ('b', 3), ('a', 6), ('b', 5)],
                           ['a', 'i'])
win = Window.partitionBy('a')
df.withColumn('avg', F.avg('i').over(win)).show()
```

Would yield:

```
+---+---+---+
|  a|  i|avg|
+---+---+---+
|  b|  3|4.0|
|  b|  5|4.0|
|  a|  2|4.0|
|  a|  6|4.0|
+---+---+---+
```

The average aggregation is done on each worker separately, requires no round trip to the host, and therefore efficient.

Comment: Thanks, but as everything already posted on this question makes clear, I was specifically asking a question about why the `combineByKey` -> `map` operation was erroring.